# Remove order number in string from Angular option value

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to make a form in Angular with a select box whose values are taken from an array. I also need the form to show inputs based on the value of that select. This is the code:

```
<select #freq formControlName="freq" class="m-2">
            <option disabled>Select</option>
            <option value="">Select Option</option>
            <option *ngFor="let x of freq_list" [ngValue]="x">{{x}}</option>
          </select>

          <div *ngIf="freq.value!=''">
            {{freq.value}}
            <div *ngFor="let x of parameter_config[freq.value]">
              <input type="number" formControlName="input1">
            </div>
          </div>
```

where freq_list is a simple `string[]=['option1',option2',option3']` and parameter_config is a map `{[id:string]: string[];}`where the id is the a value of `freq_list`.
And this is the form creation:

```
form=this.fb.group({
    freq:'',
});
```

Everything works except that the value returned by the selected option is not simply 'option1' but it is preceded by the order in the list (e.g. `'1: option1'`, `'2: option2'`, ...)

Is there something I am missing? How is this the default behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace ngValue with value

```
<option *ngFor="let x of freq_list" [ngValue]="x">{{x}}</option>
```

should be

```
<option *ngFor="let x of freq_list" [value]="x">{{x}}</option>
```

Comment: I knew it was something really easy, but i could figure out what. I works like a charm.